# Nifi record the maximum timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the timestamp value in each flow file, I need to compare the timestamp of the current flow files with previous flow files and if it is greater write that to a file using the Put file processor, at the end I need to have the max timestamp in the file. I tried this with the update attribute processor's advanced features in the following way:

Added a rule named `max_timestamp` with the condition `${getStateValue("maxTimestamp"):lt(${timestamp})}` and set the action for the attribute `maxTimestamp as ${timestamp}`

I also turned set the store state feature to store locally in the processor, but I do not see the `maxTimestamp` attribute being set to the flowfiles output from the update attribute processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `UpdateAttribute` processor to evaluate `maxTimestamp` attribute in stateful mode with following parameters:

---

```
Store State                      : Store state locally
Stateful Variables Initial Value : 0
maxTimestamp                     : ${timestamp:toNumber():math("max",${getStateValue("maxTimestamp")})}
```

the expression `${timestamp:toNumber():math("max",${getStateValue("maxTimestamp")})}`

evaluates maximum between two numbers:

`timestamp` attribute in current flowFile, 
and stored value of `maxTimestamp`

The property `Stateful Variables Initial Value : 0` defines the default value of the stored value `maxTimestamp`

---

2. then use `RouteOnAttribute` with following properties:

---

```
Routing Strategy : Route to Property name
less_then        : ${timestamp:lt(${maxTimestamp})}
```

So, you will have 2 relationships

`less_then` for case when `timestamp` is less then `maxTimestamp`

`unmatched` for other cases

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for me to keep this maximum timestamp in a file and the next time the invoke http processor starts to pull data use this last maximum timestamp.

Comment: you can use `AttributesToJSON` -> `PutFile` to store attribute(s) to file, and `GetFile` -> `EvaluateJsonPath` to read and parse from json file attributes.